# How To Call Spring MVC Controller From JQuery Ajax Call

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

i am attempting to call Spring controller method from JQuery ajax call, but its not navigate to corresponding view.

First i am verifying login details by calling authenticateLogin() Spring controller function from ajax call, after successful validate i need to forward the request to corresponding view page, i have tried with below code but its not navigate to another page.

**Javascript function:**

```
function authenticatePricingCalcLogin() {
    var login = {
            userName : $("#username").val(),
            password : $("#password").val()
    };

    $.ajax({type: "POST",
        url: CONTEXT_PATH+"authenticateLogin",
        data:JSON.stringify(login),
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != null) {
                if (response.errorMsg != null && response.errorMsg != "") { // Login Error
                    alert(response.errorMsg);
                } else {
                     // Here i need to call spring controller method and to redirect to another page

                     // I have tried
                     $.ajax({type: "GET",
                            url: CONTEXT_PATH+"navigateMainPage",
                            data:JSON.stringify(loginDO),
                            contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            dataType : 'json'
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**AuthController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authenticateLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody LoginDO authenticateLogin(@RequestBody Login login){
    return authService.authenticateLogin(loginDO);
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/navigateMainPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String navigateMainPage(@ModelAttribute("loginDO") Login login,HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    try {
        // Need to set User Name in session variable
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return "auth/mainPage";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add / in your path

**url: CONTEXT_PATH+"/authenticateLogin",**

Comment: could you check your console log in browser? I gess there must be some clue. I have faced such problems many times. Show me your console log. May be I would be able to help you.

Comment: I have checked browser log, there is no error. i think, if we use ajax again controller navigate to ajax method instead of view page.

Answer (score 0):

Hi friend I don't have Comment authority so just answering your question.just comment data part if it is `GET` Type request and remove it form java side `@ModelAttribute("loginDO") Login login`, Otherwise just make it `POST` and check any CSRF token is there or not for safe side.

Comment: Hi friend.. I have tried with post, but it remains same.. its not navigating to another page.

Comment: status 403 or anything else

Comment: are you sure if there is no error then what is the status of your request ?
add a debugger there and check what is happening there?
https://imgur.com/a/uWQTW