# How to show response from AJAX call to Spring controller method?

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-mvc

How do I display the response of a call to a Spring MVC Controller returning HTML? In my Javascript code I make a (GET) call to my Spring Controller. From what I can make is that the response from the call is HTML. I guess I need to replace 'alert(response)' with Javascript to display the html.

My Javascript code:

```
     $('#parcelsTable').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
         var data = table.row( this ).data();

         $.ajax({
             url:"/parcel/showFormForUpdate",
             type:"GET",
             data:{parcelId:data.parcelId},
             success: function(response){
                alert(response) 
             }
         });
     } );
```

My controller code in Spring:

```
@GetMapping("/showFormForUpdate")
public String showFormForUpdate(@RequestParam("parcelId") int theId, Model theModel) {

    Parcel theParcel = parcelService.findById(theId);
    theModel.addAttribute("theParcel", theParcel);
    return "parcel-form";
}
```

Here "parcel-form" is the name of a template.

Comment: Are you trying to open some dialog with that parcel-form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace html element with ajax response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527586/how-to-replace-html-element-with-ajax-response)

Comment: @barbsan, I need to show a different page to update a parcel.

Comment: You can add HTML as inner HTML to any container on your page. For example, `$('#someId').html(responce);`

Comment: my question is similar to this unanswered question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49103786/how-to-call-spring-mvc-controller-from-jquery-ajax-call

Answer (score 0):

```
     $('#parcelsTable').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
         var data = table.row( this ).data();

         $.ajax({
             url:"/parcel/showFormForUpdate",
             type:"GET",
             data:{parcelId:data.parcelId},
             success: function(response){
                $.get(response.html, function(data, status){
                $("#ID").html(data);
                }); 
             }
         });
     } );
```

response.html is the page you want to show on the success of get request. Just make a get request to the response.html file or any template file and put this file in any div where you want to show it.

Hope that it works

Comment: the contents of response is a HTML document, returned from my Spring controller. I want to be redirected to a new page containing the response. Where does $(#ID) refer to?

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution messes up with my page, because the contents of table is not showing anymore.

Comment: just to check if I understand your solution correctly... I need to create a file so that the html from the response can be inserted in and then I redirect to that file?

Comment: Yes... You just need to insert that html content file in any div with that ID..  OR else you can just simply redirect to response.html